# Gsuit admin sdk how to find what role a particular user assigned

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

It is well documneted [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986) that in Gsuit there are 6 Pre-built administrator roles and we can assign any custom role to user

- Super Admin
- Groups Admin
- User Management Admin
- Help Desk Admin
- Services Admin
- Reseller Admin

I can fetch all the roles in any gsuit account using [admin.directory.rolemanagement](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/roles/list),in response items contains list of all 6 roles-

- _SEED_ADMIN_ROLE
- _GROUPS_ADMIN_ROLE
- _USER_MANAGEMENT_ADMIN_ROLE
- _HELP_DESK_ADMIN_ROLE
- _SERVICE_ADMIN_ROLE
- _PLAY_FOR_WORK_ADMIN_ROLE

below is sample response.

```
{
 "kind": "admin#directory#roles",
 "etag": "\"BHP2ZsIq1HPrqEG_xY7Tkngn4lU/aNSm49szAAWjtQ6SLWG_peDst5I\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "admin#directory#role",
   "etag": "\"BHP2ZsIq1HPrqEG_xY7Tkngn4lU/GNyl5JrVAyPUAIIlrwnibCSKClQ\"",
   "roleId": "11870025812017153",
   "roleName": "_SEED_ADMIN_ROLE",
   "roleDescription": "Google Apps Administrator Seed Role",
   "isSystemRole": true,
   "isSuperAdminRole": true
  },
  {
  ...Role2
  },
  ....
]
}
```

But I am unable to find what role a particular user assigned

when I fetch any user details using [G Suite Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) 
getting below sample json

```
{
 "kind": "admin#directory#user",
 "id": "1071482697096977",
 "etag": "\"BHP2ZsIq1HPrqEG_xY7Tkngn4lU/xqnEb7WwzCINHQT7UJn28\"",
 "primaryEmail": "xyz@demo.zxy.com",
 "name": {},
 "isAdmin": false,
 "isDelegatedAdmin": false,,
 "suspended": false,
 "ipWhitelisted": false,
 "emails": [
  {
   "address": "",
   "primary": true
  }
 ],
 "nonEditableAliases": [""],
 "customerId": "accounts customerId",
 "orgUnitPath": "/",
 "isMailboxSetup": true,
 "isEnrolledIn2Sv": false,
 "isEnforcedIn2Sv": false,
 "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
}
```

Is there any way to Identify which of above 6 roles is assigned to user,since in admin sdk API is returning a single key **isAdmin**.Is this **isAdmin** would be true if any type of admin role is assigned to user.

Comment: I think you can use [Members: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list). If you have the [`groupKey`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list#parameters), you will be able to list all the members with corresponding roles. Check the [response](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list#response) of this method. To know more about groupKey, you can refer to [Directory API: Groups](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups).

Comment: ^ wrong, Members are relevant only to Groups. Here, OP is asking for how to figure out what roles a gsuite user is assigned to

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/roleAssignments/list?apix_params=%7B%22customer%22%3A%22C00rz37xc%22%2C%22roleId%22%3A%2241816136601305092%22%7D

You can use this API to list all the users who have been assigned a particular role (by passing the role ID) and a particular domain(the customer id).

There is an optional query parameter for user key which if passed, will help you know if that particular user has been assigned that role or not.

It will work for all delegated admins, and I guess that's what you need, because a super admin (isAdmin) anyway will have an access to that particular role.

P.S I know it's probably too late for the guy who asked this question but anyone who needed this to be figured out, this answer is for you.